# Java exception crshes play framework

Tags: java, exception, playframework, crash

I have following controller:

```
public static Result overview() {

    class Earning {
        public int ammount;
        public String description;
    }

    Earning[] earnings = new Earning[5];

    earnings[0].ammount = 5;

    return ok(overview.render(earnings));
}
```

I didn't created corresponding object in array as a result in Java I should get: java.lang.NullPointerException

But instead of showing this error Play framework crashes.

Any ideas how not to crash the framework and see the error in first place?

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
earnings[0] = new Earning();
```

before:

```
earnings[0].ammount = 5;
```

This way, `earnings[0]` will hold an `Earning` object and you would be able to access its `ammount` field.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare the Earning class inside the overview method.
It's creating a visibility issue because this class should only be accessible in the method body, but your "leaking" it by passing it to a view.